# Assign vs if statement

Tags: system-verilog

Is this:

```
  assign ON = signalA && signalB;
  always_comb begin
    case (blabla)
      case_A: begin
        if (ON) next_state = some_state;
      end
  ...
```

Equivalent to this:

```
  always_comb begin
    case (blabla)
      case_A: begin
        if (signalA && signalB) next_state = some_state;
      end
  ...
```

Do they produce the same amount of hardware? Is one better than the other?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this case they should produce the same amount of logic.

In general, `always_comb` is preferred for at least the [following reasons](http://bradpierce.wordpress.com/2009/12/04/sv-always_comb-safer-than-verilog-assign/):

- If there is a function on the right hand side and it depends on a global net or variable, then it’s more accurate to use `always_comb`, because it “is sensitive to changes within the contents of a function”.
- `always_comb` will generate warnings about inferred latches.

Equivalently, you could also write:

```
 always_comb ON = signalA && signalB;
 always_comb begin
    case (blabla)
      case_A: begin
        if (ON) next_state = some_state;
      end
 end
```

or:

```
 always_comb begin
    ON = signalA && signalB;
    case (blabla)
      case_A: begin
        if (ON) next_state = some_state;
      end
 end
```

Note that by assigning `signalA && signalB` to `ON` either by continuous assignment or `always_comb`, you are not creating extra logic. Consider it as an internal signal which exists either way, but you may or may not choose to assign a name to it. One reason to do this is for debugging and viewing the value of `signalA && signalB` on a waveform display.